# Asking a user for an input, then asking them if they are sure of their input using readline from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I've been trying to get this down for the past few days, but methods that I call after the rl.question functions keep being called before they are supposed to. I've tried directly calling the functions and tried returning results instead in hopes of something different happening, but the same thing keeps happening.

Here's my code:

```
const Entity = require('./spireb/entities/Entity.js');
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var askQuestion = function(question) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        rl.question(question, answer => {
            return resolve([question, answer]);
        });
    });
};

var confirmAnswer = function([question, answer]) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log(`You said: ${answer}`);
        rl.question('Are you sure? (Y/N): ', answer0 => {
            if(answer0.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
                return resolve(answer);
            } else if(answer0.toUpperCase() == 'N') {
                console.log('Ah, I must\'ve misheard!');
                return askQuestion(question);
            } else {
                console.log('Sorry, could you repeat that?');
                return confirmAnswer([question, answer]);
            }
        });
    });
};

//Getting player username
(async () => {
    let x =  await askQuestion('What is your username?: ').then(confirmAnswer);
    x.then(theirA => {
        global.username = theirA;
        rl.close();
    });
})();

console.log(`Your username is ${global.username}`);
console.log('Ended.');
```

This code will usually keep resulting in:

```
What if your username?: Your username is undefined
Ended
```

I understand why it tells me my username is undefined, but why does it keep skipping the part it asks the user their username?

Comment: `askQuestion` runs asynchrnously, so those `console.log` run before `global.username` is filled. Just put both `console.log`  before `rl.close` and you're good to go.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande does this mean I will have to continue the rest of my program in that space before rl.close()?

Comment: Drop the `.then` and use `await`, and it will be cleaner. But the rest of your code needs to happen there. You can use other functions, or just keep using await to keep the code clean, and without many levels of nesting.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Will i just do exactly the same thing I did here (with some modifications) whenever I want to call askQuestion() again?